# React Native - Init Dependency Component

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have two components

1. class VideoSessionScreen extends Component
2. class ChatScreen extends Component

I want to initialise `ChatScreen` inside `VideoSessionScreen` component and render it when required.

I am able to render it by using `<ChatScreen/>` inside the render of `VideoSessionScreen`.

My problem is, chat screen has `componentDidMount` which has code to fetch data from server. I want to fire `componentDidMount` of ChatScreen only once in `VideoSessionScreen`, however currently it keeps triggering `componentDidMount` of `ChatScreen` every-time it re-renders `VideoSessionScreen` (because  is places in conditional render method inside `VideoSessionScreen`), find below sample code on `render()` in `VideoSessionScreen` for reference

```
render() {
  return(
    {'video' === this.state.displayScreen &&
      <VideoScreen/>
    }
    {'chat' === this.state.displayScreen &&
        <ChatScreen/>
    }
  );
}
```

My question is, How do I initialise `<ChatScreen>` and hide/show (toggle) the component.

I tried storing  in constant, state etc. none works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

1) Don't fetch the data on the ChatScreen component. Use Redux or fetch it on the main component and pass it down.

2) Instead of doing a conditional render, display both screens but set the opacity of the visible one to 1 and of the invisible one to 0. Also use pointerEvents="none" for the invisible screen.

3) Do the same as in 2 but use animations. In shouldComponentUpdate, return false so that the component is not rerendered.

Inside of the render() method:

```
render() {
  const { displayScreen } = this.props;

  return (
    <VideoScreen opacity={'video' === displayScreen ? 1 : 0} pointerEvents={'video' === displayScreen ? 'auto' : 'none'} />
    <ChatScreen opacity={'chat' === displayScreen ? 1 : 0} pointerEvents={'chat' === displayScreen ? 'auto' : 'none'} />
  );
}
```

In your View components in VideoScreen and ChatScreen, do this:

```
render() {
  const { opacity, pointerEvents } = this.props;

  return (
    <View style={{ opacity }} pointerEvents={pointerEvents} />
  );
}
```

Comment: For #2, If lets say we toggle the visibility, will we not loose the ability for user input since one of the element will always be back and the other in front, the one in back will loose the ability for user input.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. You can instead use translateX: screenWidth or pointerEvents="none".

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, would you be able to help with an example?

Comment: And also, how would you hide a component?

Comment: Let me check the code and come back, meanwhile I just checked that react-native alos supports z-index.

Comment: Actually, I don't think z-index works very well. You could use elevation instead.

Comment: Actually working quite well, WOW, thank you, let me test further more.

Comment: I would highly recommend option 1 since it follows the idea of dumb and smart component. `ChatScreen` doesn't/might not need to know the data it is rendering and you would have much more control on when to and how to render. Opacity and z-index options means that component renders anyways and gives unnecessary load when doesn't need.

Comment: You mean passing the data or Redux way? I just started playing around with React native and I havent been through redux yet.

Comment: If you just started, don't bother with Redux. Play with React Native a little, but eventually, you will NEED Redux. It's a life-saver. :)

Comment: Sure I will, although I started only couple weeks back, the application I am working on is to go for production in couple more weeks. I hope the #2 options is not that much of an issue (ofcourse I look forward to update it with Redux as soon as I can)

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar how you develop is all up your opinion of course. Best solution is the one works for you. Although you don't have to start using Redux right away you can also pass data down to component with props without Redux.